# Setting state with async value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data for a React component and set it as a nested object in state:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import XLSX from "xlsx";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading:false,
      cards:{}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({isLoading:true});

    /* convert xlsx to JSON */
    fetch("../data/Cards_v0.1.xlsx")
    .then((d)=> d.arrayBuffer()).then((d)=>{

      const data = new Uint8Array(d);
      const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:"buffer"});
      const sheet = workbook.Sheets["Deck"];
      const cardsJSON = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet,{range:1});

      let cards = {};
      for(let i=0; i<cardsJSON.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<cardsJSON.length; j++){
          cards[cardsJSON[i].Name] = cardsJSON[i];
        }
      }
      this.setState({cards:cards, isLoading:false});
  });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.cards.Single.Name }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

React devtools shows that the object is in state, with *cards>Single>Name* being "Single", but `{this.state.cards.Single.Name}` throws **TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined.**

What's confusing me most is that `{this.state.cards.Single}` instead throws **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Name, Type, Rarity, Text, Money}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

So the key `Name` is found when it's not being called, but then the object becomes undefined when I call it?

Very confused. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React doesn't know how to display objects, therefore, `{this.state.cards.Single}` will throw `Objects are not valid as a React child`.**

You also have some odd choice of setting React state. Since the component is always going to fetch data on mount, it makes more sense to make `isLoading` to be defaulted to true, then set to false on successful fetch response.

I don't know how your `cardsJSON` is structured, but the example below shows two ways to display nested JSON.

- Wrapping it in pre, code html elements and using `JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces)`
- Destructing the object properties from `this.state.cards` (if any of these are properties that are also nested objects, then they'll also need to be destructed as well!) and then displaying all destructed data in a table, list, etc.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/km3wwvqqzv

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import DisplayCode from "./displayCode";
import DisplayList from "./displayList";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    cards: {}
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ cards: json, isLoading: false }));
  };

  render = () =>
    this.state.isLoading ? (
      <div>Loading</div>
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
        <DisplayCode cards={this.state.cards} />
        <DisplayList cards={this.state.cards} />
      </Fragment>
    );
}
```

**displayCode.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default ({ cards }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <h3>Display JSON as code:</h3>
    <pre style={{ height: 300, overflowY: "auto" }}>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(cards, null, 4)}</code>
    </pre>
  </Fragment>
);
```

**displayList.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

export default ({ cards }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <h3 style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>Display JSON as list:</h3>
    <ul style={{ height: 300, overflowY: "auto" }}>
      {map(
        cards,
        ({
          id,
          name,
          username,
          email,
          address: {
            street,
            suite,
            city,
            zipcode,
            geo: { lat, lng }
          }
        }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <strong>id:</strong> {id}
            <ul>
              <li>
                <strong>Username:</strong> {username}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {name}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Email:</strong> {email}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Street: </strong>
                {street}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Suite: </strong>
                {suite}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>City: </strong>
                {city}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Zipcode: </strong>
                {zipcode}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Lat: </strong>
                {lat}
              </li>
              <li>
                <strong>Lng: </strong>
                {lng}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        )
      )}
    </ul>
  </Fragment>
);
```